# Proportion of non-quadratic residues when added by 1 are still non-quadratic residues

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. I am interested in the set of elements $x\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x$ and $x+1$ are both quadratic non-residues. Let $N_p$ be the number of such elements. I want to calculate $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}N_p/p$. Where to begin? More generally, what kind of tools are available to study questions like this, where I am interested in proportions of elements in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying certain properties, as $p\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: The limit is one-fourth. *Cyclotomy* studies such questions systematically, although for this particular question it is overkill. And please edit the title with the correct spelling of *quadratic*.

Comment: Dear Gerry, thank you for your quick response. Could you let me know where I can learn more about Cyclotomy and how you arrived at the answer 1/4?

Comment: PS I have added the title, sorry about that.

Comment: You can type *cyclotomy* into the internet, and see what comes back at you. If you can find Tom Storer's little book on cyclotomy, that ought to do it, but that book is hard to find. There's a chapter or two in the Ireland & Rosen textbook that covers the relevant ideas, I think (I'm currently away from my references. And I see two answers have been posted, so maybe that's all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $c$ be a quadratic non-residue. Then $x$ and $x+1$ are both quadratic non-residues
iff $cx$ and $c(x+1)$ are both quadratic residues (nonzero squares modulo $c$). If so then
$xc\equiv a^2$ and $x(c+1)\equiv b^2\pmod p$, so that
$$b^2-a^2\equiv c\pmod p.\tag{1}$$
Let $M_p$ be the number of solutions of $(1)$ in the integers modulo $p$.

A solution of $(1)$ with $a$, $b\not\equiv0\pmod p$ will give rise to an $x$
with $x$ and $x+1$ both quadratic non-residues, and if we multiply $a$ or $b$
by $-1$ we get the same $x$. So the number of nonzero solutions of $(1)$ is $4N_p$.
But $(1)$ has no solutions with $a\equiv0$ as $c$ is a non-residue but it may have
solutions with $b=0$, precisely when $-1$ is a non-residue, that is when $p\equiv3\pmod 4$. So $M_p=4N_p$ or $M_p=4N_p+2$ according to whether $p\equiv1$ or $p\equiv3\pmod 4$.

But $M_p=p-1$ in all cases, since we can rewrite $(1)$ as
$$(b-a)(b+a)\equiv c\pmod p.\tag2$$
Thus $b-a$ can be any number nonzero modulo $p$ and that determines $b+a$ and so
both $a$ and $b$. Therefore $M_p=\frac14(p-1)$ or $\frac14(p-3)$
(whichever happens to be an integer) or simply the integer part of $p/4$.

Comment: I got it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this particular question (and some questions like it), here's one method.

Let $\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)$ be a Legendre symbol, so it's $0$ if $x\equiv 0\bmod p$, $1$ if $x$ is a (nonzero) quadratic residue modulo $p$, and $-1$ if it's a nonresidue. As a result, we have that
$$\left(\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)-1\right)\left(\left(\frac{x+1}{p}\right)-1\right)$$
is $4$ if $x$ and $x+1$ are both nonresidues, $0$ if one of them is a positive residue, and $2$ if $(-1/p)=-1$ and $x=-1$. So,
$$\sum_{x\in\mathbb F_p}\left(\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)-1\right)\left(\left(\frac{x+1}{p}\right)-1\right)$$
is $4$ times the number of $x$ so that $x$ and $x+1$ are both nonresidues, possibly plus $2$ if $-1$ is a nonresidue modulo $p$. Let $N$ be the answer that we seek.

The other tool we use is that
$$\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\equiv x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\bmod p.$$
As a result,
$$4N+1-\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\equiv \sum_{x\in\mathbb F_p}\left(x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1\right)\left((x+1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1\right)\bmod p.$$
Let's evaluate the sum on the right. For $p-1\nmid k$, we have
$$\sum_{x\in\mathbb F_p} x^k\equiv\sum_{j=0}^{p-2}g^{kj}\equiv\frac{g^{(p-1)k}-1}{g^k-1}\equiv 0\bmod p,$$
where $g$ is a primitive root modulo $p$, and the same result is true when $k=0$. When $k$ is a positive multiple of $p$, the result is $-1$. As a result, when we expand out the polynomial on the right side of the above congruence, every term that is of degree $<p-1$ is unimportant, and so the sum on the right is simply $-1$. As a result,
$$4N+1-\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\equiv -1\bmod p\implies N\equiv \frac{p-2+\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)}{4}\bmod p.$$
However, $N$ is clearly between $0$ and $p-1$ (inclusive), and the right side is an integer between these two values. There are no other integers congruent to the right side modulo $p$ that are between $0$ and $p-1$, and so
$$N=\frac{p-2+\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)}{4}=\left\lfloor\frac{p}{4}\right\rfloor.$$

---

Similar techniques can work for cubes, if you note that
$$x^{\frac{2(p-1)}{3}}+x^{\frac{p-1}{3}}+1$$
is $3$ if $x$ is a cubic residue and $0$ otherwise (and of course $1$ at $0$), as well as other powers if you like, but the sums become messier and more complicated.

Comment: This is very nice as well, thank you for suggesting this method!